# MySQL Left Join NULL issues

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL code:

**Working Query**

```
SELECT name, AVG(q1) AS avg 
FROM respondents 
LEFT JOIN results_new ON respondents.login_id = results_new.company 
WHERE respondents.brand = 'ABC' 
AND results_new.sdate = 'MAY2014' 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY avg 
DESC
```

The above works correctly, it brings back 35 rows and displays the name and average correctly.

**Non working query**

```
SELECT name, AVG(q1) AS avg 
FROM respondents 
LEFT JOIN results_new ON respondents.login_id = results_new.company 
WHERE respondents.brand = 'ABC' 
AND results_new.sdate = 'NOV2014' 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY avg 
DESC
```

The above returns `zero` results - which is correct as there is no data in the table for `NOV2014'.

However, what I expected to happen was the query to return 35 rows with the `name` and `NULL` next to each name.  Clearly I think my `JOIN` is incorrect but I cannot work out where I am going wrong.

Any and all advice welcomed.

Comment: Using a column of the left joined table in the `WHERE` clause changes the left join into an inner one. You've got to add this condition to the join clause.

Answer (score 5):

Your `where` clause turns your `left join` into an `inner join` since you filter on data in the joined table. Put this condition in the `on` clause of your join.

```
SELECT name, AVG(q1) AS avg 
FROM respondents 
LEFT JOIN results_new ON respondents.login_id = results_new.company  
                      AND results_new.sdate = 'NOV2014'
WHERE respondents.brand = 'ABC'
GROUP BY hotel_name 
ORDER BY avg DESC
```